# Maths is wrong: always result of 0

Tags: c#, math

So I have some code which basically reads:

```
int foo = bar * (percentage / 100);
```

Where foo represents the percentage of bar. So, if bar was 100 and percentage was 20, we would expect 20/100 = 0.2 so 100 * 0.2 = 20... but that's not what happens. Every time, without fail foo = 0. I figured 'maybe it's not a whole number' so I tried:

```
float foo = bar * (percentage / 100);
```

foo still = 0. Any help would be appreciated, as I've never been great at math, but I'm pretty sure I'm not wrong on this bit of it

Comment: What is `bar` and what is `percentage`?

Comment: integers are whole numbers only use a another data type such as decimal, double or float

Comment: bar is a number. percentage is a percentage - a number between 0 and 100. foo would be the number which is percentage percent of bar. It sounds like I'm repeating myself, but there's really no other way I can put it.

Comment: @Joe This is nothing to do with math it's type coercion or lack thereof. `foo` might be a float but the right hand side as a whole is an int. (percentage / 100) is an int and will be evaluated as such (float will be casted after). It can only be represented as whole value. Therefore, if `percentage` can only be between 0 and 100, the only case where `foo` won't be 0 is when `percentage` is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(percentage / 100)` is of type integer and as such will be 0 whenever the result rounds to 0.

If you change one of the numbers in the expression to a type that handles decimals. The expression will evaluate to that type instead.

```
(percentage / 100.0)
```

and then when you multiply it with `bar` that expression will also be of the same type rather than `int`.

Alternatively you can change the order of execution

```
int foo = (bar * percentage) / 100;
```

There will be some loss of precision but you shouldn't get 0 unless `bar * percentage` is less than 100 as well.

Comment: Oh the logic! 100 is a different number to 100.0 Of course! Thank you, I've been scratching my head at this for far too long.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to a decimal `float foo = bar * (percentage / 100.0);`

Comment: Like I said, I tried that and foo still works out as 0.

Comment: @Joe Are you sure? This isn't the same as your example. Notice the `100.0`. The `.0` makes a difference.

Comment: I hadn't even considered that 100 and 100.0 would act differently, they definitely never did when I studied math.

Comment: @Joe This is not math. This is programming. Different rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float foo = (float)bar * ((float)percentage / 100.0);
```

To round up, do this:

```
in foo = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)bar * ((float)percentage / 100.0));
```

Comment: Then round it up afterwards

Comment: @Joe: Added 'rounding up' logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is integer division. You need to do:

```
int foo = bar * (percentage / 100.0);
```

This tells the compiler you want a double or float back, not an int that will be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in (percentage / 100). It's Integer, So 20/100 = 0.
The source should: var foo = bar * (percentage / 100.0);

I hope this is helpful